# Accessing data in object inside array using php's SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

This is related to my earlier question here: [Trying to read XML nodes using PHP DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086916/trying-to-read-xml-nodes-using-php-dom)

I have an array which has elements that look like this:

```
[rpc.pingomatic.com] => Array
        (
            [http://www.example.com] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [name] => flerror
                            [value] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [boolean] => 0
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [name] => message
                            [value] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [string] => Pings being forwarded to 11 services!
                                )

                        )
            )
```

I want to retrieve the data and finally display it in this manner:
flerror:0
Message from directory:Pings being forwarded to 11 services

I can use this to retrieve the necessary fields:

```
echo $response->name;                   
echo $response->value->boolean;
echo $response->value->string;
```

However, I am using a foreach loop to traverse through the array, and not all elements have the fields named boolean and string. They might have something like flag instead of boolean, etc.

Is there a generic way to retrieve the necessary data using the same foreach loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the best way to deal with my problem is to use
 `isset($response->value->boolean)` or `isset($response->value->string)` to ascertain the type of the value and echo it out.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this method [PHP: SimpleXMLElement::xpath - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php)

Comment: There are a lot of examples in the comment section at the page given above.

Comment: Besides, there are a lot of related questions. One of them is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108721/iterating-simplexml-xpath-result